# Remove duplicate AND original values, leaving only truly unique values in notepad++

Tags: notepad++, duplicate

How to delete both original and duplicate values in a notepad++ and keep only the truly unique values?

Say I had:

```
1
1
3
```

Desired:

```
3
```

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35329122/find-duplicates-and-delete-all-in-notepad

Comment: @mashuptwice I have tried looking for same question all over the google including the stackoverflow and stackexchange but no luck.
And the post you have given is different.
The post gives the result of 1 set of original values+unique values (1, 3).
But i am looking for only truly unique values (3)
Thanks

Comment: Note that it is unclear which exact solution from the stackoverflow question you've tried. The question is only different in the data provided, it literally reads like: `I need to find and delete all (including found one)`. While the question uses text, seperated by newlines, it should be easy to adapt the regular expression in the highest voted answer to your needs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Assuming the lines are sorted:

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `(^.+\R?)\1+`
- Replace with: `LEAVE EMPTY`
- **CHECK** *Match case*
- **CHECK** *Wrap around*
- **CHECK** *Regular expression*
- **UNCHECK** `. matches newline`
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

**Explanation:**

```
(           # group 1
    ^           # beginning of line
    .+          # 1 or more any character but newline
    \R?         # any kind of linebreak, optional
)           # end group
\1+         # backreference to group 1, must appear 1 or more times
```

**Screenshot (before):**

[image]

**Screenshot (after):**

[image]